# Tool to list down all links in ASP .net project

Tags: asp.net

I have a ASP .net project with 100+ pages. There are lot of links to external pages from different pages of my project. With external page link I mean it is  pointing to some page which is not in my project.

I want to list down all the links, preferably in an excel sheet with the columns for the link & the .aspx page in which that link appeared. Is there any tool to extract the list of all links in an asp .net project?

Atul Sureka

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use this:
Neotrek Extract Links

It requires the files to be of .htm or .html extension type
so you might want to create a copy of the original folder, rename every .aspx page to
.htm or .html using some batch renamer
or using a batch command in Command prompt like:

```
ren *.aspx *.htm
```